# Nested list to array - Eloquent JavaScript chapter 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

The solution to this exercise is only partly given, if anyone could show me how to complete it and explain it that would be great. Thanks!

The list value: "values" needs to be converted to an array, such as [1, 2, 3]

```
let list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

This is given as a hint, but I'm still unsure what you could do to finish this off.

```
for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: This is homework, and you've been spoon fed. The solution is pretty simple, and it involves a two (super simple) lines of code. Try solving it. I'll be happy to help if you get stuck.

Comment: Hint: put `console.dir(node)` inside the loop, then run it & open Developer Tools in the browser to see what it outputs (in the Console tab).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
console.log(node) 
}
/* output = { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } }
            { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } }
            { value: 3, rest: null } */
```

```
let array = [];
for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
  array.push(node.value);
}
console.log(array); // output [1, 2, 3]
```